# Formula for $\pi$: what did Doron Zeilberger mean instead of $\pi = \lim_{n} \frac{4^n}{{2n \choose n}n}$?

Tags: limits, pi

I just watched the Vimeo video ["What is Pi and what it is not"](https://vimeo.com/326572230) where Doron Zeilberger talks about $\pi$. At around 16:00, he writes this on the blackboard:
$$\pi = \lim_{n} \frac{4^n}{{2n \choose n}n}$$
But that doesn't work. As $n$ increases, this expression seems to tend towards $0$.

Does anyone have a clue as to what he might have meant to write? I'm guessing the expression needs only a little adjustment.

Comment: $$\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{n(2n!)}=2\cdot4^n\frac{\Gamma^2(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}=2\cdot4^nB(n+1;n+1)=2\cdot4^n\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^ndx$$
$$\overset{x=\frac12+\frac t2}{=}\int_{-1}^1(1-t^2)^ndt=\frac1{\sqrt n} \int_{-\sqrt n}^\sqrt ne^{n\ln(1-\frac{x^2}n)}dx=\frac1{\sqrt n} \int_{-\sqrt n}^\sqrt ne^{-x^2-\frac{x^4}{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2})}dx$$
Expanding integration to $\pm\infty$ (we drop exponentially small corrections $\sim e^{-n}$)
$$\sim\frac1{\sqrt n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\left(1-\frac{t^4}{2n}+O\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)\right)dt=\sqrt\frac\pi n\left(1-\frac3{8n}+O\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)\right)$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorial is
$$n! = \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n (1 + R_1(n)) ,$$
where $R_1(n) \in O\left(\frac1n\right)$. Substituting gives that
$${2 n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2} = \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \left(1 + R_2(n)\right),$$
where again $R_2(n) \in O\left(\frac1n\right)$. Rearranging gives the limit
$$\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n} {{2 n} \choose n}} = \sqrt{\pi}} .$$

Comment: I believe in the second equality it should be $(2n)!$ instead of $(2n!)$.

Comment: @IgnacioHenríquez You're right, of course---thanks for catching the typo. It's fixed now.